# Wifi Unavaliable on redmibook 14 ryzen edition

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, network-manager, atheros

Thats what I have after trying a lot of guides to find a solution for my problem

Firstly I was having network disabled and also unavaliable state in `nmcli dev status`
and now I dont even have my wlp1s0. I've never used linux before thats my first time trying it and i'm already spent a lot of time trying everything I can find and nothing helps

Also from time to time wlp1s0 appears back but with network disabled as I understand it happens after full ath10k firmware reinstall

```
rfkill list 

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

lshw -C network
 *-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:61 memory:c0200000-c03fffff

lspci
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

UPD:
reinstalled linux firmware

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

and giving more info

```
sudo dmesg | grep ath10k

[   10.195632] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   10.898669] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[   10.898681] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   10.899805] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 90eebefb
[   11.137789] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=11ad,subsystem-device=0847 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[   11.143179] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[   11.235831] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   14.415913] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   17.487954] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   17.487964] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   17.487968] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   17.595939] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
[   17.638600] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   23.119915] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   23.119924] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   23.119928] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[   26.191933] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   26.191944] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   29.263937] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   29.263951] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   29.263956] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   32.847933] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   32.847940] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   32.847944] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[   35.920156] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   35.920168] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   38.992355] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   38.992366] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   38.992369] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   42.576373] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   42.576383] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   42.576386] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   45.648369] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   45.648384] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   48.720362] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   48.720372] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   48.720376] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   62.287952] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   62.287962] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   62.287965] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[   65.363924] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   65.363933] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   68.432167] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   68.432178] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   68.432182] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   72.015936] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt version request timed out
[   72.015951] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to setup htt: -110
[   72.096748] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[   77.392191] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   77.392200] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   77.392205] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[   80.463919] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   80.463932] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   83.539930] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   83.539941] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   83.539945] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   87.164613] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   87.164624] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   87.164628] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   90.263543] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[   90.263552] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   93.353393] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[   93.353404] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   93.353407] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   96.954801] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[   96.954811] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[   96.954814] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[  100.030077] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[  100.030088] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  103.106914] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[  103.106925] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  103.106929] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  106.694561] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[  106.694570] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  106.694574] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[  109.772554] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[  109.772563] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  112.841866] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[  112.841876] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  112.841879] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  116.426830] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[  116.426838] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  116.426841] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[  119.499378] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[  119.499384] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  122.571740] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[  122.571747] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  122.571750] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  126.156015] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[  126.156024] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  126.156028] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: -11
[  129.228567] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[  129.228580] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  132.296891] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[  132.296901] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  132.296905] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  135.848781] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[  135.848792] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  135.848795] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  138.904299] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[  138.904309] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  141.962951] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[  141.962962] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  141.962966] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  145.536475] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
[  145.536487] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  145.536491] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  148.603083] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 16389 timeout, restarting hardware
[  148.603094] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  151.669956] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wmi command 69633 timeout, restarting hardware
[  151.669967] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: already restarting
[  151.669970] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
```

and

```
    lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0847]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

before tried

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/2.0/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
```

doesn't working for me maybe just because of wrong board.bin file if someone has another sources of it for QCA6174 would be nice to try out them too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was

```
rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin 
wget https://github.com/vpm/RedmiBook16-QCA6174/raw/main/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
wget https://github.com/vpm/RedmiBook16-QCA6174/raw/main/firmware-6.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
```

reboot